# Computed Column Formula and how it can work base on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this challenge.  I want to achieve a formula in a computed column.  Currently my formula is: `((((([sponsorID]+' ')+substring(CONVERT([varchar],datepart(year,[DateCreated]),(0)),(3),(4)))+'-')+'0')+CONVERT([varchar],[ID],(0)))`

Where: sponsorID, DateCreated, ID are columns in my table PatientInfo.

A sample of what the formular produce is **PVT 11 10567**

My ID column auto increment

Now The total no of record in my table called PatientInfo is getting to 500,000.  and the formula i was given is [SPONSORCODE YEAR - 4 DIGIT].  It must not exceed 4 digit!

How do i achieve this formula in such a way that the id stops when a year ends and start afresh in a new year. i.e. patient folder no can be PVT 10 0128 ....... and PVT 11 0128.  this is because in a year the total no of new patients will not exceed 4 digits.  aside from the existing patients.

PLEASE Kindly assist.  i hope i have provide a clear picture of my challenge.  if there is a better way to achieve this, please assist.

awaiting your reply.

Comment: Why so many parentheses?

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: they are added by SQL Server

Comment: @Rahmat isn't there a "-0" missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it work to use the last 4 digits of ID? For the ID part of the expression, you could use:

`RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar,[ID]),4)`

Of course, you could get duplicates if you ever inserted more than 9999 rows in a particular year.

Comment: No problem.  It was so long ago, I'd forgotten about it!

Answer (score 0):

You can't using a computed column based on ID

You'd need a separate incrementing column per year and per sponsor that allows only 0000-9999. Then, use this in your computed column.

In the next version of SQL Server, you can use a sequence. Until then, you could use a sequence emulator: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx